# Let me hurl this riddle to you

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge

Role 1: These people do things in mountains, pastures, hills, fields, forests...

Role 2: These people do various things. They can find you a house, a hotel, send you something, kill you...

Role 3: Atom....in English

**Who is the one with the above roles?
Bonus: What role is missing?**

Comment: Am I correct in thinking of Rot13 tur enere hfr bs "ngbz" - nf n havg bs gvzr?

Comment: @Brandon_J nope

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I think I have all the pieces to this one...

*Role 1: These people do things in mountains, pastures, hills, fields, forests...*

> SETTLER. The listed location types are playable spaces in the board game *Settlers of Catan*.

*Role 2: These people do various things. They can find you a house, a hotel, send you something, kill you...*

> AGENT (as per @JohnLaRocque's answer: "*real estate agent, travel agent, mail agent, secret agent*").

*Role 3: Atom....in English*

> INDIVIDUAL - you can't really get much more 'individual' than a single atom. We even use the adjective 'atomic' to mean "of or forming a single irreducible unit or component in a larger system" (Source: OED).

Now, as to who might be 'the one with the above roles':

> I believe from a lot of Googling - boy, is someone going to have some fun with my search history now - that being the 'Settler, Agent and Individual' is something to do with citizenship or legal terminology, with particular connotations to the 'Sovereign Citizen' movement in the States - a group who rejects federal law and refuses to be bound by it.

In which case, the role that is missing may well be:

> The PERSON, which web-famously features heavily in a probation hearing between one such 'citizen' and a judge in a video and transcript from 2014 which occasionally goes viral every now and then and does the rounds on the Internet...

This would fit with the title too since:

> The judge in this particular viral video is Judge **Hurl**ey, hence the use of 'hurl' in the title...

Comment: I didn't believe this would be solved! Congratulations! Had a great laugh with this video!

Comment: By the way, why don't you do one last step and explain the title too?

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis As a board game buff it was recognising Catan that did it for me! The rest fell into place with the connection to 'agent'...

Comment: Nice job with the title too :)

Comment: [Stories in the news currently](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/59870550) reminded me of this puzzle from a few years back. When I gave this answer I had never previously heard anything at all about this movement - strange to think, mid-pandemic, that this topic has come back around again...

Answer (score 5):

Not a full answer, but,

> "Agent" fits Role 2 suspiciously well.  (real estate agent, travel agent, mail agent, secret agent)

Comment: Mail agent? Is that a thing?

Comment: [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Estate+agent%2C+Travel+agent%2C+mail+agent%2C+secret+agent&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2CEstate%20agent%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bestate%20agent%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BEstate%20Agent%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BESTATE%20AGENT%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2CTravel%20agent%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Btravel%20agent%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BTravel%20Agent%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BTRAVEL%20AGENT%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BTravel%20agent%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cmail%20agent%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmail%20agent%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMail%20Agent%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsecret%20agent)

Comment: This is correct!

Answer (score 5):

Could it be

> The book: "Indivisible (Native Agents)" by Fanny Howe

Role 1: These people do things in mountains, pastures, hills, fields, forests...

> Native, all things are in nature

Role 2: These people do various things. They can find you a house, a hotel, send you something, kill you...

> Agents (Like @John LaRocque already said)

Role 3: Atom....in English

> Indivisible, Atoms are indivisible

Comment: Nope, that's not it. However, you are really close to role 3